# libcurl: I am unable to download web resources as fast as a browser

Tags: curl, libcurl

Check this simple web page, if you wish: http://alvein.freevar.com
It's just a plain gallery of 1999 small images.

Both Chrome and Edge complete the full load **below 10 secs** *(with an empty cache)*.
An external test tool like this one, https://tools.pingdom.com, gets similar values.

However, I've not been able to code any downloader close to such speeds.

Not gonna post my source code (yet) for simplicity of this question.

For now, I'll say that I have two versions, based on these libcurl samples:

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/10-at-a-time.html *(single-thread, simultaneous downloads)*
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html  *(multi-thread)*

I extended both samples, loading the contents of *urls[]* either by hand or directly parsing the  resource links from the sample gallery. Meh, this is not important.

I also added a "pool" for both methods the way the number of resources and threads (or "slots" for the 1st sample) can be variable.

But the rest is pretty much identical.

For the same web page and resources, my times are always **over one minute**, and I wonder why.

What does the browser do to get everything so fast? Or maybe libcurl isn't really suited for this kind of tasks?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

PD. These samples were built and tested with VS2017, x64, release.

**EDIT**

Not sure if my connection was crawling before (doubt), but in latter runs, *I'm getting below-10-secs times as well*.

As requested, this is my code (warning: long).

```
// Parallel downloads sample - based on https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/10-at-a-time.html

#include <time.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

// Available download slots. The smaller the download resources, the higher this value can be.
// Can't be too big or the failing fopen_s() will make some slots impossible to fill.
#define MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS 200

typedef struct {
    int  iIndex;
    char *szURL;
    char *szPath;
} ProgressHelper;

typedef struct {
    unsigned __int64 ui64Size;
    char             *cData;
} DownloadHelper;

typedef struct {
    int            iTotalDownloads;
    bool           *bDownloaded, *bDownloading;
    char           **szURLs, **szPaths;
    FILE           **fDownloads;
    CURL           **curlDownloads;
    ProgressHelper *phProgress;
    DownloadHelper *dhDownload;
} MultiDownloadHelper;

CURLM *curlMultiHandle;

CURL *curlSharedHandles[MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS];

bool bBusyHandles[MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS];

const char *szSourceURL = "http://alvein.freevar.com";
const char *szDownloadFolder = "C:\\Users\\Alvein\\Avatars";

static size_t write_callback(char *data, size_t size, size_t nitems, void *userdata) {
// write_callback(): receives incoming download data and "saves" it in a DownloadHelper structure.
    unsigned __int64  ui64DataSize = size * nitems;
    DownloadHelper    *dhCurrentDownload = (DownloadHelper *)userdata;
    char              *cDownloadedData = (char *)realloc(dhCurrentDownload->cData,
                                                         dhCurrentDownload->ui64Size + ui64DataSize);
    if(NULL!= cDownloadedData) {
        // Saves the downloaded chunk (data) at the end of the downloaded data (cDownloadedData)
        if (0 == memcpy_s(cDownloadedData + dhCurrentDownload->ui64Size,
                          dhCurrentDownload->ui64Size + ui64DataSize,
                          data,
                          ui64DataSize)) {
            dhCurrentDownload->cData = cDownloadedData;
            dhCurrentDownload->ui64Size += ui64DataSize;
            return ui64DataSize;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static int progress_callback(void *userdata, curl_off_t dltotal, curl_off_t dlnow, curl_off_t ultotal, curl_off_t ulnow) {
// progress_callback(): just a simple callback for future use.
    ProgressHelper *phCurrentDownload = (ProgressHelper *)userdata;
    if(dltotal)
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: %lld of %lld\n", phCurrentDownload->szURL, dlnow, dltotal);
    return CURL_PROGRESSFUNC_CONTINUE;
}

bool singleDownload(const char *szURL, char **cContentData, unsigned __int64 *ui64ContentLength) {
// singleDownload():  downloads the resource in szURL.
// cContentData:      returned array of bytes (not a string). Must be released by caller.
// ui64ContentLength: the content length written in cContentData.
    bool           bResult = false;
    CURL           *curlHandle;
    DownloadHelper dhSingle = { 0,NULL };
    *cContentData = NULL;
    *ui64ContentLength = 0;
    curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
    if (NULL != curlHandle) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, szURL);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &dhSingle);
        if (CURLE_OK == curl_easy_perform(curlHandle))
            if (dhSingle.ui64Size) {
                *cContentData = dhSingle.cData;
                *ui64ContentLength = dhSingle.ui64Size;
                bResult = true;
            }
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
    return bResult;
}

bool multiDownload_StartOne(MultiDownloadHelper *mdhHelper, int iIndex) {
// multiDownload_StartOne(): adds a given download job to the multi interface
    bool bResult = false;
    int  iK;
    FILE *fHandle;
    CURL *curlHandle;
    if (0 == fopen_s(&fHandle, mdhHelper->szPaths[iIndex], "wb")) {
        // Finds a free download slot
        for (iK = 0; iK < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iK++)
            if (!bBusyHandles[iK])
                break;
        if (iK < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS) {
            curlHandle = curlSharedHandles[iK];
            bBusyHandles[iK] = true; // Seizes the download slot
            mdhHelper->fDownloads[iIndex] = fHandle;
            mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iIndex] = curlHandle; // Assigns the shared handle to this job
            mdhHelper->phProgress[iIndex] = { iIndex,mdhHelper->szURLs[iIndex],mdhHelper->szPaths[iIndex] };
            mdhHelper->dhDownload[iIndex] = { 0,NULL }; // Resets the download progress
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, mdhHelper->szURLs[iIndex]);
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &mdhHelper->dhDownload[iIndex]);
            #ifdef _DEBUG // Progress is disabled in Release - too much stuff on the console
                curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0L);
                curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, progress_callback);
                curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, &mdhHelper->phProgress[iIndex]);
                fprintf(stderr, "multiDownload_StartOne(%d)...\n", iIndex);
            #endif
            curl_multi_add_handle(curlMultiHandle, curlHandle);
            bResult = true;
        }
    }
    return bResult;
}

void multiDownload(MultiDownloadHelper *mdhHelper) {
// multiDownload(): performs all the download jobs contained in mdhHelper.
    int     iK, iJ, iActiveDownloads, iTotalDownloaded, iActiveHandles, iPendingMessages;
    CURLMsg *curlMessage;
    // Finds every not-completed/not-busy download job...
    iActiveDownloads = iTotalDownloaded = 0;
    for (; iActiveDownloads < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iActiveDownloads++) {
        for (iK = 0; iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads; iK++)
            if (!mdhHelper->bDownloaded[iK])
                if (!mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK])
                    break;
        if (iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads)
            mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK] = multiDownload_StartOne(mdhHelper, iK); // ...and starts them...
        else
            break;
    } // ...as long as there are no more than MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS active jobs
    do {
        curl_multi_perform(curlMultiHandle, &iActiveHandles);
        do {
            curlMessage = curl_multi_info_read(curlMultiHandle, &iPendingMessages);
            if (NULL != curlMessage) {
                // Finds the index of the download job the received message belongs to
                for (iK = 0; iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads; iK++)
                    if (curlMessage->easy_handle == mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK])
                        break;
                if (iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads) {
                    if (CURLMSG_DONE == curlMessage->msg) {
                        if (CURLE_OK == curlMessage->data.result) {
                            long lResCode;
                            curl_easy_getinfo(mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK], CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &lResCode);
                            // The response code is ignored in this sample (let's assume it's always HTTP 200 OK)
                            mdhHelper->bDownloaded[iK] = true;
                            mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK] = false;
                            iTotalDownloaded++;
                            fwrite(mdhHelper->dhDownload[iK].cData,
                                   sizeof(char),
                                   mdhHelper->dhDownload[iK].ui64Size,
                                   mdhHelper->fDownloads[iK]); // Saves the downloaded file in a single shot
                            #ifdef _DEBUG
                                fprintf(stderr, "\nDownload is complete (%ld): %s\n", lResCode, mdhHelper->szPaths[iK]);
                            #endif
                        }
                        else {
                            fprintf(stderr, "\n**Download failed (%d): %s\n", curlMessage->data.result, mdhHelper->szPaths[iK]);
                            mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK] = false;
                        }
                        fclose(mdhHelper->fDownloads[iK]);
                        mdhHelper->fDownloads[iK] = NULL;
                        curl_multi_remove_handle(curlMultiHandle, mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK]);
                        // Instead of calling curl_easy_cleanup(mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK])...
                        for (iJ = 0; iJ < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iJ++)
                            if (curlSharedHandles[iJ] == mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK])
                                break;
                        bBusyHandles[iJ] = false;            // ...frees the associated download slot...
                        mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK] = NULL; // ...where mdhHelper->curlDownloads[iK] is in
                        iActiveDownloads--;
                        if (iTotalDownloaded < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads) {
                            // Finds all the pending download jobs, and starts them...
                            for (; iActiveDownloads < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iActiveDownloads++) {
                                for (iK = 0; iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads; iK++)
                                    if (!mdhHelper->bDownloaded[iK])
                                        if (!mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK])
                                            break;
                                if (iK < mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads)
                                    mdhHelper->bDownloading[iK] = multiDownload_StartOne(mdhHelper, iK);
                                else
                                    break;
                            } // ...as long as there are no more than MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS active jobs
                        }
                    }
                    else // Improbable to happen
                        fprintf(stderr, "\n!!Unknown message (%d): %s\n", curlMessage->msg, mdhHelper->szPaths[iK]);;
                }
                else // Impossible to happen
                    fprintf(stderr, "\n!!Could not find the messaging handle in the downloads list\n");
            }
        } while (NULL != curlMessage);
        if (iActiveHandles) // Gives one second to the active and non responsive downloads...
            curl_multi_wait(curlMultiHandle, NULL, 0, 1000, NULL); // ...before continuing the messages poll
        else
            if (iTotalDownloaded == mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads)
                break; // Exits if every download job has finished
    } while (true);
}

void allocMultiDownloadHelper(MultiDownloadHelper *mdhHelper, int iHowMany) {
// allocMultiDownloadHelper(): allocates the required memory for every download job.
    mdhHelper->iTotalDownloads = iHowMany;
    mdhHelper->bDownloaded = (bool *)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(bool));
    mdhHelper->bDownloading = (bool *)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(bool));
    mdhHelper->szURLs = (char **)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(char *));
    mdhHelper->szPaths = (char **)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(char *));
    mdhHelper->fDownloads = (FILE **)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(FILE *));
    mdhHelper->curlDownloads = (CURL **)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(CURL *));
    mdhHelper->phProgress = (ProgressHelper *)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(ProgressHelper));
    mdhHelper->dhDownload = (DownloadHelper *)malloc(iHowMany * sizeof(DownloadHelper));
}

void freeMultiDownloadHelper(MultiDownloadHelper mdhHelper) {
// freeMultiDownloadHelper(): releases the memory allocated for every download job.
    for (int iK = 0; iK < mdhHelper.iTotalDownloads; iK++) {
        free(mdhHelper.szURLs[iK]);
        free(mdhHelper.szPaths[iK]);
        free(mdhHelper.dhDownload[iK].cData);
    }
    free(mdhHelper.bDownloaded);
    free(mdhHelper.bDownloading);
    free(mdhHelper.szURLs);
    free(mdhHelper.szPaths);
    free(mdhHelper.fDownloads);
    free(mdhHelper.curlDownloads);
    free(mdhHelper.phProgress);
    free(mdhHelper.dhDownload);
}

void parseHTMLImgTags(char *szHTML, char ***szImgSources, int *iTotal) {
// parseHTMLImgTags(): shameless <img> tags parsing in the HTML content supplied in szHTML.
//                     Not to be taken seriously.
// szImgSources:       returned array of URLs as NULL-terminated strings.
// iTotal:             the number of image URLs found.
    unsigned __int64 ui64ImgSrcLen;
    char             *szHTMLNdx, *szImgSrc, **szRllSources,
                     *szImgTagStart, *szImgTagEnd, *szSrcAttStart, *szSrcAttEnd;
    *iTotal = 0;
    *szImgSources = NULL;
    szHTMLNdx = szHTML;
    do {
        szImgTagStart = strstr(szHTMLNdx, "<img ");
        if (NULL != szImgTagStart) {
            szImgTagEnd = strstr(szImgTagStart + 5, ">");
            if (NULL != szImgTagEnd) {
                szSrcAttStart = strstr(szImgTagStart, "src=\"");
                if (NULL != szSrcAttStart) {
                    szSrcAttEnd = strstr(szSrcAttStart + 5, "\"");
                    if (NULL != szSrcAttEnd) {
                        ui64ImgSrcLen = szSrcAttEnd - szSrcAttStart - 5;
                        szImgSrc = (char *)malloc(ui64ImgSrcLen + 1);
                        if (0 == strncpy_s(szImgSrc, ui64ImgSrcLen + 1, szSrcAttStart + 5, ui64ImgSrcLen)) {
                            szImgSrc[ui64ImgSrcLen] = '\0';
                            szRllSources = (char **)realloc(*szImgSources, (*iTotal + 1) * sizeof(char *));
                            if (NULL != szRllSources) {
                                *szImgSources = szRllSources;
                                (*szImgSources)[(*iTotal)++] = _strdup(szImgSrc);
                            }
                        }
                        free(szImgSrc);
                    }
                }
            }
            szHTMLNdx = szImgTagEnd + 1;
        }
    } while (NULL != szImgTagStart);
}

int main(void) {
    int                 iResult = EXIT_FAILURE, iK, iTotalDownloads;
    unsigned __int64    ui64HTMLSize;
    char                *cHTML, *szImgExt, **szURLs, szLocalFile[MAX_PATH];
    double              dblElapsed;
    time_t              tmTimer;
    FILE                *fHTML;
    MultiDownloadHelper mdhDownloads;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    time(&tmTimer);
    // Downloads the source web page
    if (singleDownload(szSourceURL, &cHTML, &ui64HTMLSize)) {
        dblElapsed = difftime(time(NULL), tmTimer);
        iTotalDownloads = 0;
        szURLs = NULL;
        sprintf_s(szLocalFile, MAX_PATH, "%s\\source.html", szDownloadFolder);
        (void)fopen_s(&fHTML, szLocalFile, "w");
        if (ui64HTMLSize) {
            // Saves the content in the download folder
            fwrite(cHTML, sizeof(char), ui64HTMLSize, fHTML);
            cHTML = (char *)realloc(cHTML, ui64HTMLSize + 1);
            if (NULL != cHTML) {
                cHTML[ui64HTMLSize] = '\0'; // Assumes the content is HTML - handles it as ASCIIz
                parseHTMLImgTags(cHTML, &szURLs, &iTotalDownloads);
            }
        }
        fclose(fHTML);
        free(cHTML);
        if (iTotalDownloads) {
            // Initializes every handle in the download slots - sets them as "available"
            for (iK = 0; iK < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iK++) {
                curlSharedHandles[iK] = curl_easy_init();
                bBusyHandles[iK] = false;
            }
            allocMultiDownloadHelper(&mdhDownloads, iTotalDownloads);
            // Initializes the download jobs (1 per image resource)
            for (iK = 0; iK < iTotalDownloads; iK++) {
                #ifdef _DEBUG
                    fprintf(stderr, "Image resource: %s\n", szURLs[iK]);
                #endif
                mdhDownloads.bDownloaded[iK] = mdhDownloads.bDownloading[iK] = false;
                mdhDownloads.szURLs[iK] = szURLs[iK];
                // Makes the local filename for each job - just a numeric sequence, for simplicity
                mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK] = (char *)malloc(MAX_PATH * sizeof(char));
                sprintf_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, "%s\\%05u", szDownloadFolder, iK);
                // Adds a file extension, based on the image resource URL - rudimentary method
                szImgExt = strrchr(szURLs[iK], '.');
                if (NULL != szImgExt)
                    if (szImgExt == strstr(szImgExt, ".jpg"))
                        strcat_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, ".jpg");
                    else if (szImgExt == strstr(szImgExt, ".png"))
                        strcat_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, ".png");
                    else if (szImgExt == strstr(szImgExt, ".gif"))
                        strcat_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, ".gif");
                    else
                        strcat_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, ".tmp");
                else
                    strcat_s(mdhDownloads.szPaths[iK], MAX_PATH, ".tmp");
            }
            curlMultiHandle = curl_multi_init();
            curl_multi_setopt(curlMultiHandle, CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS, MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS);
            fprintf(stderr, "Downloading %d images...\n", iTotalDownloads);
            time(&tmTimer);
            multiDownload(&mdhDownloads);
            dblElapsed += difftime(time(NULL), tmTimer);
            curl_multi_cleanup(curlMultiHandle);
            freeMultiDownloadHelper(mdhDownloads);
            for (iK = 0; iK < MAX_SIMULTANEOUS_DOWNLOADS; iK++)
                curl_easy_cleanup(curlSharedHandles[iK]);
            fprintf(stderr, "Load time: %0.2f\n", dblElapsed);
            iResult = EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not find a single image resource the source web page\n");
    }
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not download the source web page\n");
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return iResult;
}
```

I know it's pretty fast now, but any additional suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you very much guys for the ideas about reusing the handles.

Comment: Are you using HTTP/1.1 persistent connections? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: I suggest you read the section titled "PERSISTENT CONNECTIONS" on [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl.html#PERSISTENT) of the official documentation. Are you reusing handles? Or are you creating a new handle for every HTTP request?

Comment: @Alvein Web browsers are HIGHLY optimized for speed.  They not only use PERSISTENT connections, but also MULTIPLE connections, as well as PIPELINING and MULTIPLEXING, etc.  Things that are specifically designed to speed up request handling.  Whether you not your libcurl code is able to do the same things, we can't say, because you have not shown what your code actually looks like.

Comment: @all, thanks for the hints about persistent connections. I did the homework and for both approaches, I was able to halve the times.

I'd need to halve them again to make them look like a browser's, though.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: according the last paragraph of that section, I shouldn't do any edits for the first sample since it's using the multi interface, but it was necessary to cut times.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: apart of multi-threading, I wouldn't know what more to do. In fact, using threads does not seem to be a step ahead of the single-thread simultaneous method. I'll try to post my code tomorrow. It's a mess right now.

Comment: @Alvein I didn't say anything about using multiple threads. And again, if you don't show us your actual code, we can't help you speed it up.

Comment: According to [this page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_PIPELINING.html) of the documentation, `CURLPIPE_MULTIPLEX` is enabled by default in libcurl version `7.62.0` and higher. What version are you using?

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel: 7.68.0

Comment: if you have PHP available, can you bechmark the C code vs the PHP code i posted below? i'd love to see the numbers

Answer (score 0):

> Or maybe libcurl isn't really suited for this kind of tasks?

[image]

ill try to download that as fast as i can using curl_multi, a single thread with multiple connections, using PHP (* doing it in C would be even faster, but it's just easier for me to do it in PHP, and i think PHP will be fast enough to prove my point that it isn't curl's fault anyway, we'll see)

this code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

const MAX_CONCURRENT_CONNECTIOS = 100;
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$workers = [];

$work = function () use (&$workers, &$mh) {
    // > If an added handle fails very quickly, it may never be counted as a running_handle
    while (1) {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $still_running);
        if ($still_running < count($workers)) {
            break;
        }
        $cms = curl_multi_select($mh, 10);
    }
    while (false !== ($info = curl_multi_info_read($mh))) {
        // echo "NOT FALSE!";
        // var_dump($info);
        if ($info['msg'] !== CURLMSG_DONE) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($info['result'] !== CURLM_OK) {
            // cba doing proper error detection
            throw new \RuntimeException("curl error");
        }
        $key = (int) $info["handle"];
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $info['handle']);
        curl_close($info['handle']);
        // var_dump($workers[$key]);
        fclose($workers[$key]["fp"]);
        unset($workers[$key]);
    }
    // echo "NO MORE INFO!";
};
$ch = curl_init('http://alvein.freevar.com/');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
));
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$domd = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
// just to make sure the garbage collector doesn't do something stupid..
// probably not needed
foreach ($domd->getElementsByTagName("img") as $img) {
    while (count($workers) >= MAX_CONCURRENT_CONNECTIOS) {
        $work();
    }
    $url = $img->getAttribute("src");
    $fp = fopen(basename($url), 'wb');
    if (! $fp) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("fopen failed!");
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
        CURLOPT_FILE => $fp,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "benchmark_not_empty",
        // CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
    ]);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    $workers[(int) $ch] = [
        "handle" => $ch,
        "fp" => $fp
    ];
}
while (count($workers) > 0) {
    $work();
}

echo "all images downloaded!";
```

runs in about 5.3 seconds on my 50mbit 2.4Ghz wifi'ed connection in Norway..

and when i run it on a 1gbps connection from Canada, it runs in about 1.1 seconds.. maybe it will go even faster if i play with the `const MAX_CONCURRENT_CONNECTIOS = 100;` setting? anyway i'm out of time

(optimization notes: re-using worker handles rather than creating+deleting 1-time-use them would be even faster)

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. Got a total boost by reusing handles.
Now I'm getting a solid 6 sec on a 10mb connection.

Comment: @Alvein cool, btw re-using handles is an optimization *notably* missing from the php code above ^^ (cba trying now though, copypasted the above during my lunchbreak, i'm still at work for the next 5 hours till 15:30 UTC+0, gotta do some real work now)